# Laravel's Eloquent not-foreingKey-function?

Tags: laravel, function, eloquent

I have a interessant qüestion.

Looks this code (works good):

```
class WaterWell extends Model
    {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'player_id',
        'well_level',
    ];

    public function cosa()
    {
    $pepe = Rule::select('value')->where('rule_name', $this->well_level)->first();
    return $pepe;            
    }
}
```

when i want to acces this data via API:

```
class PlayerController extends Controller
{
public function showPlayer($id)
{
    $player = Player::with('animals', 'animals.animal_type', 'water', 'food')->findOrFail($id);

    $pepe = WaterWell::where('player_id', $id)->first()->cosa();

    $player->water->pepe = $pepe;

    return [
        'status' => 1,
        'player' => $player            
    ];
}
}
```

this works good, but is it possible to do this more cleanly?

Something like this : (this not works)

```
$player = Player::with('animals', 'animals.animal_type', 'water', 'water->cosa()', 'food')->findOrFail($id);
```

I would love the 'water.cosa()' or 'water->cosa()' on one Eloquent line.

Its posible?

thanks

Comment: Is there a relationship between the classes? a foreign key

Comment: no, because its from a not-relationed-table called "rules" where I save ther all the constants. As u see when i search Rule::select('value')->where('rule_name', ... etc

Comment: Even without a physical relationship in the database, you can create a relation in the models for them to communicate, since you have a connection column in where. Try to use a `hasOne` passing the manual keys. I believe it should work for you to be able to call it in `with()`. You can also add joins to this relation with `hasOne()->join()` if needed.